# Rendering Question

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm unsure about something when it comes to rendering and was hoping someone could shed some light and help me understand. I've noticed whenever doing renders in Blender that the frame rate is always low, even if settings have been lowered and the model has no textures, particles, physics etc.

Even using a good graphics card like the GTX 1080, I only get around 20fps in some renders.

I understand the process it has to go through to output a model, so it converts it to a 2D image to be displayed on screen, but why are renders so demanding on hardware?

Yet every highly detailed model that features in a game scene is no problem? I can achieve 60+ fps with settings maxed out etc.

Comment: Rendering is all about faking real physics. Cycles tries to do a lot as real as possible, games try to fake as much as possible. Depending on your requirements you can find a happy medium in the settings.

Comment: If you have not read up on [EEVEE](https://www.blender.org/2-8/) you might wish to do so.  It is an upcoming renderer for Blender that is designed for much better real-time performance.

Comment: Please make your title specific to what you are asking, instead of just the general topic.

Comment: EEVEE, huh. Cool. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: The thing is that games use the Rasterization render engines, while blender Cycles is a Ray Tracing engine. Rasterization basicaly gets 3d vector and convert to pixels, trying to fake light and shadows, which is not very demanding. Raytracing in the other hand needs to process each light path, and thats is something that our computers can't do fast enough to get a perfect performance. Thats why blender has it's viewport "rasterization mode", which is fast enough to work with. If you want to know more search for **ray tracing**

Comment: Ahhh, that makes perfect sense. Thank you. I've recently covered rasterisation and ray tracing for a 3D modelling assignment at college. :) What's Blender's rasterization mode? How's this enabled? Or this going to be a part of EEVEE?